# Can I download a file from a website with a download link? Visual Basic

Tags: html, vb.net, download

Is it possible to download a file from a website that offers a download button? I am trying to make a simple program that will download texture packs for Minecraft and install them automatically. When prompted for the URL for the texture pack, the user has to use the direct download URL, which means right-clicking the download button in their browser, and clicking 'copy link location'. This seems more convoluted than just downloading and manually installing, so is it possible to use the link provided on the download page?

I don't know how it would be done, but I have one rather inefficient method - the URL is inputted, and the HTML page downloaded. Then the file is scanned for a string that looks like a download link, and is tested. If it returns something, then happy days. If not, it will look for another download link in the HTML file.

I can't think of anything else that would work, and even that seems a little dubious. Sorry if I sound naive, I am new to programming.

Comment: If you are able to download texture packs from any site and not just a specific one: this will probably be extremely hard because there's pretty much no way for your application to know where your download is. Doing it the way you suggested may work but the problem is that it may find other downloads to if there are more before the texture pack on that page. Since texture packs are in .zip files make it check if the link ends with ".zip", or if the last part of the link (everything after the last "/") CONTAINS ".zip". Note that some addresses may end with "/blablabla.zip?forcedownload".

Comment: Ok, so if there is no other method than the one I suggested, then how would I go about coding that?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you, but I have not yet had the time to sit down and assemble a working code for you. I will get back to you with code tomorrow. :)

Comment: That's fine :) I'm in no rush! Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So here's a possible solution for you.

Sadly it only works if the link is complete. (Starts with http:// etc...)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ScanForZIPs()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ScanForZIPs()
        Dim Reader As New StreamReader("<path to the downloaded webpage>")
        Dim HTMLSource As String = Reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim Pattern As String = "(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*" 'Pattern, which the Regex will use in order to match links in the webpage.
        'Credits to IronRazerz (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/ironrazerz/?ws=usercard-mini) for giving me a fully working pattern.
        Dim RgEx As New Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 'Define the Regex.

        Dim mc As MatchCollection = RgEx.Matches(HTMLSource) 'Check for matches in the HTML source.

        Dim MatchList As New List(Of String) 'List of strings for the matched links.

        For Each m As Match In mc 'Loop through each match.
            MatchList.Add(m.Value) 'Add the value (link) of each match to the MatchList.
        Next

        Dim ZipsList As New List(Of String) 'List of links that ends with .zip.

        For Each s As String In MatchList 'Loop through each string in MatchList.
            If s.ToLower.ToString.EndsWith(".zip") = True Then 'Check if the link ends with .zip.
                ZipsList.Add(s) 'Add the link to the list.
            End If
        Next

        MessageBox.Show(ZipsList.Count & " .zip files found", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) 'Display how many .zip files were found on the page.

        Dim SelectZip As New SelectDownload 'Define a new download form.
        For Each z As String In ZipsList 'Loop through the found .zip links.
            SelectZip.ListBox1.Items.Add(z) 'Add them to the list in the SelectZip form.
        Next
        SelectZip.ListBox1.HorizontalScrollbar = True 'Horizontall scrollbar in SelectZip's ListBox.
        SelectZip.ShowDialog() 'Display the SelectZip form.
    End Sub
End Class
```

The SelectDownload form. :)

[image: The SelectDownloaf form.]