# How can I write a regular expression that will allow a URL with or without the "HTTP://" part

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I'm looking to write a regular expression to validate a potential web address.

In 'http://www.microsoft.com' for example, I would like the make the 'http://' optional so if only 'www.microsoft.com' were entered into my textbox, it would still work.

I've done some research on regular expressions and my question specifically, but I'm not getting anywhere with finding one or really understanding how to write one.

I already have the regex provided in VS to validate an internet address, I'm more unsure of how to modify it to make parts optional.

Comment: use `(<optional_part>)?` or `(?:<optional_part>)?` if your engine supports so-called 'non-capturing groups' (meaning they don't count for backreferencing - if that's Double Dutch to you right now, forget about the 2nd version for the time being)

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed! I think I understand these a tad more now, too.

Comment: You can have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651460/can-i-download-a-file-from-a-website-with-a-download-link-visual-basic/27679709#27679709 | It was made for detecting links that ends with .zip.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are kind of difficult (in my opinion).  If you want to use Regex, more power to you.
You could use something simple like this, too.

```
If (links.StartsWith("https://") or links.StartsWith("http://") or links.StartsWith("www.")) Then
    //links are valid
End If
```

Comment: He said he wanted the "http" to be optional.  Not the "www".  So sounds like he does want "stackoverflow.com" to be invalid.

Comment: For this particular assignment, I needed to get an actual expression. Which the initial comment to my post provided. However, CrazyPaste, your answer could help me with a side project of mine. A thanks to you too!